# ASP.net MVC - How to enable deferRender and serverSide for DataTable via Ajax Calls

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I want to use deferRender and serverSide to speed up datatables because my search results are more than 5000 and is slowing down the browser.

See my view code below. I don't think deferRender and serverSide is working.

datatables.net has given an example in their website. 
But the example given in datatables.net website is slightly different than what I am using.

In my case, I use ajax to call the url and then inside success I assign data to the dataTable.

Would appreciate help from experts.

## Thanks

```
@model IEnumerable <ReportObj>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/ViewLayout.cshtml";
}

<button type="button" class="ladda-button btn btn-warning" data-style="contract" id="btnSearch">Search</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <div id="datasection">
     <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
        <thead>
           <tr class="titlerow">
            @{int i = 0;
              foreach (var property in Model.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties())
              {
                 if (i.Equals(1))
                 {
                   <th class="no-sort" style="background-color:   #5fbeaa; color: white;">
                   <input type="checkbox" id="SelCntrl" name="allcb" />Quoteid
                   </th>
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    <th class="no-sort" style="background-color:   #5fbeaa; color: white;">@property.Name</th>    
                  }
                i++;
               }
             }
             </tr>
          </thead>
         <tbody>
         @foreach (var modelItem in Model)
         {
             <tr class="contentrow">
             @{
               int j = 0; string cbname = "cb";
               foreach (var property in modelItem.GetType().GetProperties())
               {
                  if (j.Equals(1))
                  {
                    <td>
                    <input class="checkbox checkbox-inverse"
                           type="checkbox"
                           value="@property.GetValue(modelItem)"
                           id="@String.Concat("cb", @property.GetValue(modelItem))"
                           name="@String.Concat("cb", @property.GetValue(modelItem))"
                           onclick="Chboxclick(this, this.checked, '@String.Concat("cb", @property.GetValue(modelItem))')" />
                    @property.GetValue(modelItem)
                </td>
                }
                else
               {<td>@property.GetValue(modelItem)</td>}
               j++;
         }
       }
     </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
<script>    
    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        SearchBtnFunc();
    });

   function SearchBtnFunc()
    {
      var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable();
        table.destroy();
        $("#datasection").html("LOADING....");
        table.deferRender = true;
        table.serverSide = true;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/mycontroller/Search?Param=" ,
            type: "GET",

            success: function (data) {
                $("#datasection").html(data); 
                TableManageButtonsNoSort.init();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Data Error : ' + data.responseText);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: " I don't think deferRender and serverSide is working". What's your reasoning for this? You haven't actually described what is happening, instead of what you expected to happen. Also, how is your code different from the example? You think that's an important detail (or else you wouldn't have mentioned it), so please clarify what you changed. Also couldn't you have taken a few moments to format your code properly so it's easily readable :-)?

Comment: Please put some effort to format your question to be readable.